# Python logic assitance branching from main algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, tkinter, logic

I am having some issues with some Python code, which is down to my logic. I have a main function which is called via a button click within the UI, within this function depended on the result of the button click several statements will be executed, what I am having issues with is branching to functions and then returning to this point to execute the next function call. Here is my code:

```
                return #This is where I want this function to terminate and then return to the function above to execute the nextFunctionCall() function.
```

would appreciate any help, thanks. The problem I am having here is that each function is ran once and the first function should be executed 30 times and then execute the else clause, providing the status changed in the elif statement has not occurred.

Comment: The value of period is the same every time you run the function. Your "period +=1: statement is useless.

Comment: The lambda call recalls the functions passing through the new values, in this case period so the +=1 does work.

Comment: `global`... off to a bad start :-(

Comment: what type of object is root? is it really needed to provide a callback to sleep?

Comment: Yes, otherwise, the GUI will go into sleep for the specified time, root schedules the task within the GUI.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to execute `nextFunctionCall(root)` after 30 calls to `alarmActive`, you don't need to complicate yourself. Just remove it from `enableCode` and call it in the `else` block:

```
def alarmActive(root, period=0):
    # ...
    else:
        nextFunctionCall(root)
```

However, you can reduce a lot of redundant code. For instance, if you want only to set `Flash` from True or False vice-versa, and also print `"On"` and `"Off"` depending on the value, this is shorter and more direct:

```
def alarmActive(root, period=0):
    global Flash
    if period <30 and AlarmStatus == "On":
        Flash = not Flash
        print("On" if Flash else "Off")
        period += 1
        print(period)
        root.after(500, lambda: alarmActive(root, period))
    else:
        if (AlarmStatus == "Off"):
            print("Alarm has been disabled before activation")
        nextFunctionCall(root)
```

Comment: yes this is what I was doing but the nextFunctionCall is similar to the above the alarmActive function and has alot of execution paths and it ends up going back to previous functions etc

Comment: Could you post the `nextFunctionCall` function as well? If it is similar to `alarmActive`, then you just need to refactor both functions instead of worrying about how to call one aftter the other.

Comment: Its ok human error was the problem I was rescheduling the first function in my sub functions, thanks.